# My jsonpath expression returns two results when I expect just one

Tags: ruby, jsonpath

This piece of ruby code returns [1,1] but I expect to get just [1].  If I put the same text and jsonpath expression through http://jsonpath.com then I get [1]. Is this a bug in the 'jsonpath' gem?

```
require 'jsonpath'

string = <<-HERE_DOC
[
    {"processId":1,"process":"XX"},
    {"processId":2,"process":"YY"}
]
HERE_DOC
jsonpath = "$..[?(@.process=='XX')].processId"

path = JsonPath.new(jsonpath)
result = path.on(string)
puts "result: #{result}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It  seems that the problem is the extra point, in your jsonpath expression without this works similar in the two behaviours, you only need to go down one step:

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'jsonpath'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> jsonpath = "$.[?(@.process=='XX')].processId"
=> "$.[?(@.process=='XX')].processId"
[3] pry(main)> path = JsonPath.new(jsonpath)
=> #<JsonPath:0x00007f8c5bf42f10
 @opts={},
 @path=["$", "[?(@.process=='XX')]", "['processId']"]>
[4] pry(main)> string = <<-HERE_DOC
[4] pry(main)* [
[4] pry(main)*     {"processId":1,"process":"XX"},
[4] pry(main)*     {"processId":2,"process":"YY"}
[4] pry(main)* ]
[4] pry(main)* HERE_DOC
=> "[\n    {\"processId\":1,\"process\":\"XX\"},\n    {\"processId\":2,\"process\":\"YY\"}\n]\n"
[5] pry(main)> result = path.on(string)
=> [1]
```

[image: jsonpath web example]

Comment: Thank you @anquegi.  It is sort of surprising that the original version works at all - albeit inconsistently between JSONPath implementations.